# Custom failure message for Jest test

Tags: jestjs

I'm testing a function with partially randomized input. The pieces of the input object that are randomized should work no matter what but if I happen to get a case that fails I'd like to know what it is by including the invalid input in my failure message.

How can I get Jest to show a failure message that extends further than just the contents of `expect`?

Here is the code I have:

```
    describe("my module", () => {
      it("should pass with some randomized inputs", () => {
        const partialRandomInput = {
          name: "Hardcoded",
          age: Math.random() * 100,
          yearsOfExperience: Math.random() * 30
        };
        const actualOutput = myModule(partialRandomInput);

        expect(actualOutput).toEqual(false); // If this fails I only see the expect comparison that happened, which may not be helpful
      });
    });
```

Perhaps in my code above, the only failure would be if the randomized `age` is less than 5 *and* the randomized `yearsOfExperience` is less than 10. I'd like to see the values used for `partialRandomInput` when my test fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Do not test with random input.

Even if the code is meant to be used with random number, you should test it with predefined values to ensure it's consistent results. By using random numbers you cannot ensure that the used input will cover the same "branches" within the implementation.

What you can try instead is have a predefined set of values and expected results

```
describe.each([
  [10, 10, true],
  [22, 10, false],
  [35, 11, true],
  [50, 3, false],
  [60, 7, false],
])(
  "with age: %p and yearsOfExperience: %p",
  (age, yearsOfExperience, expected) => {
    it(`should return: ${expected}`, () => {
      expect(
        myModule({
          name: "Hardcoded",
          age,
          yearsOfExperience,
        })
      ).toEqual(expected);
    });
  }
);
```

---

**But** in order to answer the question - you can generate the random numbers before the execution of the test and you can then either:

1. [Extend expect](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectextendmatchers)
2. Add the value within the description of the test

```
describe.each(
  Array.from(new Array(10), () => [Math.random() * 100, Math.random() * 10])
)("with age: %p and yearsOfExperience: %p", (age, yearsOfExperience) => {
  test(`returns false`, () => {
    expect(
      myModule({
        name: "Hardcoded",
        age,
        yearsOfExperience,
      })
    ).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

Comment: Great, this is very helpful, both for explaining the direct answer to my question and for pointing out a better approach.

Comment: 'Do not test with random input' - why? Entire frameworks exist for generative testing (quickcheck, test.check), this is a great way to actually find bugs in programs and not just get a sense of false security by running the same input over and over again.

Comment: @sesm if my code has a corner case bug that wasn't caught when i ran the random-input unit tests. when you make some changes and then run tests which fail, you might think your changes caused the tests to fail. in multi-person teams, unit tests are a way to let devs identify quickly if their code breaks any existing code or not.

Comment: @AweSIM did I understand correctly that you are talking about test reproducibility issue? To fix this issue generative testing frameworks print RNG seed in case of failure, so that anyone can re-run test with exactly the same RNG seed